# Is there a way to change a class based on if a variable is true of false?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this code:

```
data-ng-class="{'fa-code': modal.wmdPreview == true, 'fa-laptop': modal.wmdPreview == false}"></span>
```

Is there a way that I could simplify this with some sort of true / false check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-class="modal.wmdPreview ? 'fa-code' : 'fa-laptop'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-class="{fa-code: modalwmdPreview, fa-laptop: !modalwmdPreview}"
```

or

```
ng-class="{true:'fa-code', false:'fa-laptop'}[modalwmdPreview]"
```